# How can I optimize this query

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I am fighting this since yesterday morning but i still cannot get it working fast enough.

The `items` table has the `artist` and the `name` fields as varchar.
All other fields are integers of various types indexed.
I have tested the query with or without the indexes on the two varchar fields and no change.

The `items_categories` has three columns: `id`, `item_id` and `cat_id`.
`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` has no affect whatsoever.

I have 65k records in both tables, each item having one category thus one relation in the `items_category` table.

The culprit query.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `items`.`id`
  FROM `items`
    LEFT JOIN `items_categories` ON `items`.`id` = `items_categories`.`item_id`
  WHERE `items`.`id` > 0 AND `items`.`hidden` = 0 AND `items`.`deleted` = 0 AND `items_categories`.`cat_id` IN(1)
  GROUP BY `items`.`id` 
  ORDER BY `items`.`artist` ASC, `items`.`name` ASC
  LIMIT 0, 100;
```

This is what explain shows me.

```
"id"    "select_type"   "table" "type"      "possible_keys"                          "key"  "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "Extra"
"1"     "SIMPLE"       "items_categories"   "ref"                                    "item_id,cat_id"   "cat_id"    "4" "const" "12152" "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort"
"1"    "SIMPLE"        "items"  "eq_ref"    "PRIMARY,hidden,deleted,hidden_deleted" "PRIMARY"   "4" "staviny_db.items_categories.item_id"   "1" "Using where"
```

The whole thing takes about 0.2 - 0.3 seconds.
I know it is due to the order clause is responsible for half that time.

Is there anything I could do to at least cut my time in half without major changes?

Comment: Your use of an OUTER JOIN seems to be redundant as you check for a value from items_categories in the WHERE clause. Change the LEFT OUTER JOIN to an INNER JOIN. Also, as you only return the items.id field, do you need to sort into artist / name order?

Comment: True, LEFT join is pointless, problem is this query is constructed and the conditions in other use cases are different, but this is the only use case causing issues as the others have more conditions that make the job easier for mysql. Yes I do need the order because the results are used to list the items. The data of the items is cached so just the ID is needed.

Comment: Fair enough. But you appear to have ~12k resulting rows which you then need to sort twice (once for the GROUP BY and then once for the ORDER BY). The GROUP BY is at least using an index (I expect DISTINCT would normally be quicker), but the ORDER BY is not indexed. Might be worth putting an index on hidden / deleted / artist / name, then trying a STRAIGHT_JOIN to force the order of the join. But this will only be useful if there are a low number of records on items and / or a large number that are not hidden or deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your query.

- You use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, yet in the `WHERE` clause you say `AND "items_categories"."cat_id" IN(1)` which makes the `OUTER JOIN` effectively an `INNER JOIN` because each row in `"items"` that has no corresponding record in `"items_categories"` will return `NULL` for `"items_categories"."cat_id"` and thus get eliminated by the `WHERE` clause
- There quite a bit of blogs that indicate that `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` can have a negative effect on performance; are you sure you really need it ?
- I'm confused you can do `GROUP BY "items"."id"` and then follow it with `ORDER BY "items"."artist" ASC, "items"."name" ASC`. I'm used to MSSQL and this simply will not compile!?!
- I'm assuming that the the GROUP BY is there because the JOIN would cause 'doubles' as multiple records in "items"categories" might fit the requirements. If so, you should rather use a `WHERE EXISTS` construction instead of doing the actual JOIN and then GROUPing everything again to get rid of them. (same story for DISTINCT which is just a fancy GROUP BY anyway)

Hence, I would suggest this:

```
SELECT "items"."id"
  FROM "items"  
 WHERE "items"."id" > 0 
   AND "items"."hidden" = 0 
   AND "items"."deleted" = 0 
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT *
                  FROM "items_categories" 
                 WHERE "items_categories"."item_id" = "items"."id"
                   AND "items_categories"."cat_id" IN (1) )
 ORDER BY "items"."artist" ASC, "items"."name" ASC
 LIMIT 0, 100;
```

(which --more or less-- would also compile in MSSQL =)

Comment: Thank you. This is much faster, but if you move the subquery into the select area using GROP_CONCAT to eliminate duplication and HAVING to ensure it's not null it will work twice as fast. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `items`.`id`
FROM `items`
LEFT JOIN `items_categories` ON `items`.`id` = `items_categories`.`item_id`
WHERE `items_categories`.`cat_id` = 1 AND `items`.`hidden` = 0 AND `items`.`deleted` = 0 
GROUP BY `items`.`id` 
ORDER BY `items`.`artist`, `items`.`name`
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

Comment: i have remove `items`.`id` > 0 because i thing id will never in Minus

Comment: I added that cause sometimes having the group by field in the where clause can speed things up. I also tried to put the cat_id first in where, no joy, same time.

Comment: Try to avoid group by, it always slow-down query.

Comment: Either group by or use DISTINCT. In this case DISTINCT seems 5% slower or that can be just an artefact of other stuff running on mysql.

Comment: what you think what will be possibility ???
take example
cat_id=100 records
hidden=75 records
deleted=40 record

then put delete clause first then hidden and then cat_id....

just think what will be possibility and change that

Comment: however distinct will not make that much slow as group by

Comment: i have 0 deleted and 0 hidden, but in the future more will be hidden then deleted

Comment: then good suggestion, use distinct instead of group by. and less record in DB put first in where clause. I know its hard to identify which clause will contain less record in column. but just study that case and implement like that.. Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Using `group by` already orders the results, so you are orderign them twice. Maybe you could use only an `GROUP BY` clause:

```
     SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `items`.`id`
      FROM `items`
 LEFT JOIN `items_categories` ON `items`.`id` = `items_categories`.`item_id`
     WHERE `items`.`id` > 0 
       AND `items`.`hidden` = 0 
       AND `items`.`deleted` = 0 
       AND `items_categories`.`cat_id` IN(1)
  GROUP BY `items`.`artist` ASC, `items`.`name` ASC, `items`.`id` 
     LIMIT 0, 100;
```

I suppose that you have already the right indices created, don't you?

Comment: Yes I have the indexes. Your query is much slower: 3-4 seconds. Group seems to take more than order. I used group by to avoid DISTINCT but both perform almost the same but group seems faster.

Comment: I would not assume that the `GROUP BY` will always return the results in that given order. Yes; internally it will order and aggregate the results and assuming it all works on one thread it (probably) will return the results in said order. HOWEVER, once the system decides this might work better on multiple threads, all bets are completely off! If you want your results in a given order, then explicitly ask for it by adding an `ORDER BY`. Never rely on implicit things; they'll work as expected on (small) test-sets but will bite you in the *** after the thing is live for a while.